# javascript multiple commands on the same object

Tags: javascript

I'd like to write something like this :

```
object
.method1("blah");
.method2("blah");
.method3("blah");
```

or

```
object
.method1("data1");
.method1("data2");
.method1("data3");
```

instead of:

```
object.method1("data1");
object.method1("data2");
object.method1("data3");
```

Is it possible ? Thanks

Comment: no.. but you can do: ocject.method1("data1").method2("data2").method3("data3");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining is possible, but only as a single statement, the extra semi-colons must go

```
object
.method1("data1")
.method1("data2")
.method1("data3")
```

you also need method1() to return an instance of the object

```
function method1(stuff) {
    // do something with stuff
    return this;
}
```

This is an idiom that is seem in DOM manipulation APIs in  frameworks such as jQuery and Dojo.

Comment: Bear in mind that it's not always a spectacular idea to do this, though. It might be much more readable to write your code the longer way.

Comment: I agree, not something I personally am a fan of, however who am I to disagree with jQuery? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like bellow

```
var obj = {};
obj.method1 = function (param) {
    console.log(param);
    return this;
}

obj.method2 = function (param) {
    console.log(param);
    return this;
};

obj.method3 = function (param) {
    console.log(param);
    return this;
};

obj.method1("First").method2("Second").method3("Third")
```